# Not getting scroll position in Iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working in salesforce1, I want to set the position of scroll bar but i am not able to get the current position of scroll bar in Iphone.

I tried everything like `window.scrollTop()`, `window.pageyOffset` but all are returning `0`.

```
<img src="......." onclick="getScrollTop();"/>
```

```
function getScrollTop(){ 
    alert($(window).scrollTop()); 
    alert(parent.window.pageYOffset); 
}
```

Please help if anyone knows how to get and set scroll position in Iphone

Comment: How can we help you debug something we can't see? Please show your code in the question.

Comment: <img src="......." onclick="getScrollTop();"/>

function getScrollTop(){
         alert($(window).scrollTop());
         alert(parent.window.pageYOffset);
}

when i run this code in browser i get exact position of scroll bar, but in Iphone this method always shows 0.